# Bluetooth problems. Intel Dual Band Wireless AC-7260

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, bluetooth, network-adapter, acer-aspire

Yesterday I installed new WIFI-Bluetooth adapter into my laptop. It is ***Intel Dual Band Wireless AC-7260*.**(*Mini PCI-E)*
I installed all drivers (for bluetooth and WiFi) from **Intel** website, but **BT adapter** is not in the **Device Manager**. When I turned my laptop (Acer Aspire, win 10) on, **BT** adapter showed there (in DM) for 30 sec and then dissapeared. When I press *"View" --> "Show hidden devices"* in **Device Manager** it shows *"Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)"* adapter as "...not connected to the computer".

By the way, I saw some tricks with tape on some pins to make Bluetooth work, but it didn't work for me.
Have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this network card is corrupted...

Comment: Apparently Acer doesn't whitelist hardware, but hardware for whitelisting machines can be problematic [according to this forum post](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/270316/#Comment_270316). Does yours come from a HP or Lenovo laptop?

Comment: I have Acer laptop. Wifi works fine 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz, but my laptop doesn't recognize BT adapter.

Comment: I'm asking about the adapter. Was it removed from a HP or Lenovo laptop?

Comment: It was bought man. It's new...

Answer (score 1):

Press the keyboard button that used to toggle Wi-Fi on/off. It should also toggle Bluetooth now.

Comment: No, that didn't work.I think the problem is deeper...

Comment: Did you try pressing it again? Does anything happen when you do it?

Comment: I pressed it (while holding FN button) several times. Nothing happened.

Comment: What laptop model is this exactly?

Comment: Acer - Aspire E5-571P-55TL

Answer (score 0):

I think, That it was a net card problem, because bluetooth did't work on **another laptop** either, so it was just manufacturing defect.